# Problem in segment creation in Apache UNOMI

Tags: apache-karaf

I was exploring Unomi from past 2 weeks, during this process I created user session and events and created few segment on user properties and event type but I got stuck when I wanted to create segment on event properties.

To start with this is the event that we are sending to unomi -

```
{
   "source":{
       "itemType":"pageView",
       "scope":"the-coolest-website",
       "itemId":"pageView"
   },
   "events":[
      {
         "eventType":"view",
         "scope":"the-coolest-website",
         "source":{
            "itemType":"pageView",
            "scope":"the-coolest-website",
            "itemId":"pageView"
         },
          "properties":{
               "myProperty":"myValue"
          }
      }
   ]
}
```

What we are trying to do is to create a segment which targets events which have this myProperty:myValue key-value pair.

The segment which I created is as follows:

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "id": "myPropertySegment",
        "name": "myPropertySegment",
        "scope":"the-coolest-website",
        "description": "The user has this segment if it has acessed our products Website.",
        "readOnly": true
    },
    "condition": {
        "parameterValues": {
            "subConditions": [
                {
                    "parameterValues": {
                        "propertyName": "myProperty",
                        "comparisonOperator": "equals",
                        "propertyValue": "myValue"
                    },
                    "type": "eventPropertyCondition"
                }
            ],
            "operator": "and"
        },
        "type": "booleanCondition"
    }
}
```

In above Event properties segment users are not being qualified having event property as "myProperty":"myValue".

Created another segment on event Type :

```
{
    "metadata": {
        "id": "eventCondition",
        "name": "eventCondition",
        "scope": "the-coolest-website",
        "description": "The user has this segment if it has acessed our products Website.",
        "readOnly": true
    },
    "condition": {
        "parameterValues": {
            "subConditions": [
                {
                    "parameterValues": {
                        "propertyName": "eventType",
                        "comparisonOperator": "equals",
                        "propertyValue": "myAwesomeUserEvent"
                    },
                    "type": "eventTypeCondition"
                }
            ],
            "operator": "and"
        },
        "type": "booleanCondition"
    }
}
```

In above Event type segment users are being qualified having eventType as myAwesomeUserEvent.

Please help me while creating segment on event properties  and let know if I am doing any mistake while creating segment.